# Wget - Saving a file to a local directory named after link

Tags: wget, redirection

I'm new to using wget, so I hope this is not a dumb question :

How can I save a file to a local directory that has been named after the link to the file ?

It does not seem to work if a redirection was involved in the download.

For instance: say I'm downloading a file from `www.abc.com/news/xyz.jif`, I can get wget to save a local copy to a directory named `www.abc.com` with sub directory `news` and then file `xyz.jif`.

If however the file `xyz.jif` was moved to `www.qwerty.com/old/xyz.jif` and the search was re-directed there, the file is still saved under `www.abc.com`...etc

As I said, I'm new to this, so I hope I've explained the problem correctly.

Here's a simple real world example (using wget):

```
wget --force-directories www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg
```

it is saved to : c:\www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg , which is *incorrent*. It should have saved it to `c:\suz.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg`, where it was redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't catch the point initially. So, a complete new answer (quick and dirty - and since it's bash programming, it works only with linux): use cURL to determine if there's a redirect (using `-w` parameter); depending on the result, use wget to get either the original url or the redirect target:

```sh
url=www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg; redirurl=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" --output /dev/null --silent ${url}`; if [ -z $redirurl ]; then wget -x $url; else wget -x $redirurl; fi
```

Or, on multiple lines:

```sh
url=www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg;
redirurl=`curl -w "%{redirect_url}" --output /dev/null --silent ${url}`;
if
    [ -z $redirurl ];
then wget -x $url;
else wget -x $redirurl; fi
```

`redirurl` is set to the redirection target if there is any. If not, `wget` is called with the original url; if yes, `wget` calls the redirection target. The `-x` parameter makes `wget` create the subdirs.

Of course, this handles only one level of redirection. To make it more robust, you'ld have to check recursively if there's a redirection. So, it isn't just a matter of command line options if you want to solve this issue in a reliable way.

Comment: I tried that already , it does not work unfortunately. It still saves the file under the original URL , not the redirected one :0(

Comment: I don't think I've been clear in my explanation , sorry. I want wget / curl to automatically save the file with the same directory names from where it got the file. From my first post get file from www.abc.com/news/xyz.jif , but file has been moved to www.qwerty.com/old/xyz.jif , unknown to me. At the end of the download file will be in c:\www.qwerty.com/old/xyz.jif , assuming I ran wget/curl from C drive

Comment: Here is a simple example (using wget) that you can reproduce quickly. wget --force-directories www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg it is saved to :  c:\www.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg  , which is INCORRECT. It should have saved it to c:\suz.smugmug.com/photos/1235566-S.jpg , where it was redirected to. In the curl example you have been given , you are telling it where to save the files. It must automatically grab the redirected url , which you wont know obviously.

Comment: Sorry, now i understand - i've removed my comments and changed my answer.

Comment: I'm not using linux , but that has pointed me in the right direction!! That "write_out" function of curl is pretty powerful. Must spend some time getting to know it. I have what I need now. Thanks again!!